# Read-only variable is not assignable c++ template function

Tags: c++, template-function

I'm trying to write my own template swap function, but something is wrong with this code:

```
template <class T>
void swap_universal(T &a, T &b) {
    T tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}
```

On this two lines : `a = b` and `b = tmp` I get an error `read only variable is not assignable`. I am using Xcode.

UPD: That's the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
void swap_universal(T &&a, T &&b) {
    T tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}

template <typename T>
void quick_Sort(const int &start, const int &end, const vector<T> &mas/*, const vector<T> arr*/) {
    int left = start, right = end;
    int middle = rand() % (end - start) + start;
    while (left < right) {
        while (mas[left] < middle)
        left++;
        while (mas[right] > middle)
            right--;
        if (left <= right) {
            swap_universal(mas[left], mas[right]);
            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }
    if (start < right)
        quick_Sort(start, right, mas);
    if (end > left)
        quick_Sort(left, end, mas);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    vector<int> t;
    for (int i = 100; i >= 0; i--) {
        t.push_back(i);
    }
    quick_Sort(0, t.size() - 1, t);
}
```

As you can see, new swap function is called inside the `quick_Sort` function

Comment: with what do you *call* this function?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also include the *actual*, complete and unedited error output.

Comment: You are calling the function with a const object as argument

Comment: What's wrong with `std::swap`?

Comment: @Nim, see my edited question

Comment: @JoachimPileborg see my edited question

Comment: The vector `mas` is a reference to a *constant* vector, you can't modify it. Drop the `const` keyword in the argument declaration.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, oh, thanks, stupid mistake

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, post this as answer, so I can accept it, pls

Answer (score 0):

I think without seeing the call site we can deduce what's happened.

A *temporary* cannot bind to a mutable l-value reference. It can bind to a mutable r-value reference or a const reference.

so when calling your function, this is one example of something that cannot compile:

```
extern Foo make_a_new_foo();
Foo f;
swap_universal(f, make_a_new_foo());
```

A const reference is no good for you because you want to modify the referent. So what you really want is a template function that deduces that a and b are either r-value references or l-value references depending on context.

Fortunately c++ takes care of this magic for you when you specify r-value reference syntax in deduced context (in this case T is being evaluated in deduced context because its type is dependent on selecting a correct type for T).

This will work:

```
template <class T, class U, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, std::decay_t<U>>::value>>
void swap_universal(T &&a, U &&b) {
    T tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}
```

Comment: This answer is rather misleading. The code with `Foo` [wouldn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f9c47c32456e16dd), but for different reasons that the OP claims: `const` can never be deduced in this case. And the forwarding-reference case does not actually use forwarding, so it would fail rather cryptically with move-only types.

Comment: @Angew your linked example does not match my answer.

Comment: I misunderstood your answer, then. I took it as "(a) here's code with which the OP's code would exhibit the OP's error, and (b) here's how to solve it." But the first code you show does *not* exhibit the OP's error.

Comment: First of all, thanks for starting a conversation on this. As a result I have seen a problem with my first solution (fixed). On reflection I accept your position. My assumption about the OP's specific use case is not correct. Having said that, I still offer the answer because the (revised) swap function seems to me to be likely to be close to what the OP wants. (i.e. a swap that works on both r-value and l-value references)

Comment: Seems unlikely that this is the explanation; that would give an error about the binding failing, not a `const` problem

Comment: ah now that there is more context in the question, I can see that it's because your vector is const. That makes everything in it const also.